# GA view shows non-existing Top Page for a domain

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using GTM and GA.

When I view one of my domains in GA, it shows me a non-existing URL as the "Top Page":

[image]

What might be the cause of this?

I've visited all the other domains that I'm tracking and which do have this /ar/downloads.htm URL, but none of them triggered this, so I would tend to think that my tracking works correctly.

When I visit the domain in the screenshot and add /ar/downloads.htm, I get a 404 error as expected, and GA doesn't me as an active user.

Can anybody tell me what might be happening here?

Thank you very much!

Edit: Attached is the Custom Report as requested:
[image]

Comment: You could check if the url is a frequent landing page with a lot of bounces and the hostname not set - that would indicate spam traffic sent via the measurement protocol (i.e. bypassing your website).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do to identify errant hits.

Create a custom report with:

- `Dimensions`: `Page`, `Hostname`, `Data Source`
- `Metrics`: `Hits`

What do you see? If `Hostname` is `(not set)` or something not under your control, it's a spammer. Otherwise Hostname should tell you where your errant code is.

Comment: Thank you. I've created such a custom report. I've added a screenshot of it to my post. Does this screenshot contain the info that is important?

Comment: Edit: I've clicked "Secondary dimension" and then selected "Hostname". The list shows several hits that are not this domain: It lists "...keys" instead of "board". "...keys" is also my domain, but they're not linked or so.

Comment: It looks like "...keys" has your GA code running on it and sending it to the GA property you use for "board". You should inspect these pages for the code.

Comment: I'm using GTM to manage GA. The 2 domains share a download counter. How should I got on inspecting what goes wrong?

Comment: I suggest using the [Google Analytics Debugger Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) to get a sense of what hits are being generated and dispatched on the offending pages